# measure of Cantor type set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Prove that the Lebesgue measure of the set $\{x\in[0,1]: \text{decimal expansion of $x$ contains only finitely many 7s}\}$ is zero.

I have thought that that if i can show that measure of $\limsup A_k$ is 1, then it is proven, where

$$A_k=\bigcup_i^{9^{k-1}} \left[\frac{10i+7}{10^k},\frac{10i+7}{10^k}\right]$$

($A_k:={}$set of $x$ such that $k$th decimal is $7$)

But by Borel Cantelli I have found that $\limsup A_k$ has measure zero. I think, the set in the questions is  the complement of $\limsup A_k$. Any help or improvement or disproof of my statements are welcome.

Comment: I believe your union should go up to $10^{k-1}-2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be the set of numbers in $[0, 1]$ such that the decimal expansion doesn't contain any $7$s. By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/76342/4583), $m(A) = 0$.

Let $B$ be the set of numbers in $[0, 1]$ such that the decimal expansion contains finitely many $7$s, and the rest are all $0$s. Since $B$ is a subset of $\mathbb Q$, it's countable.

Let $X$ be the set in your question. We have
$$
X \subset \bigcup_{b \in B} (A + b).
$$

By the translation invariance of the Lebesgue measure, we have
$$
m(X) \le \sum_{b \in B} m(A + b) = 0.
$$

Comment: very cool :) thank you bro

Comment: @Tony Happy to help!