# How to find Lebesgue measure of following set?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A = \left \{x \in [0,1] \cap ({\mathbb{R}}- {\mathbb{Q}})
 \left| \begin{array}{ll} {\textrm{in decimal expansion of } x, \textrm { say } 0.{a_1}{a_2}{a_3}\ldots \\ \textrm{first 1 (if exist) is followed by 2 }}
 \end{array}
 \right. \right \}$. What is the measure of $A$? I guess that it is 0. But don't know how to proceed. Please any help

Comment: This set has, in particular, $[0.12, 0.13) \cap (\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q})$ as a subset, so it can't have measure 0.

Comment: ok I got. so what will be its measure.

Comment: The set of all rational numbers in [0, 1] has measure 0 so the set of all irrational numbers in that interval has measure 1.  I don't know what you mean by "first 1 (if exist) is followed by 2 (if exists)".  What do you mean by "1 (if exists)" and "2 (if exists)"?  "1" and "2" certainly exist!

Comment: If I understand it correctly, it's "all irrational numbers such that the first "1" in their decimal expansion is followed by a "2", provided a "1" exists in their decimal expansion".

Comment: wherever first time 1 occur in decimal expansion it followed by 2.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following disjoint sets
\begin{eqnarray}
A_i &=& \left\{x \in [0,1]\cap(\mathbb R -\mathbb Q)|\text{the first $1$ in x's decimal expansion exists and is followed by $i$}\right\}\\
B &=& \left\{x \in [0,1]\cap(\mathbb R -\mathbb Q)|\text{x has no $1$'s in its decimal expansion}\right\}
\end{eqnarray}
Your set is $A_2$. From symmetry it should be clear that $m[A_i] = m[A_j]$ for all $i,j$, and we also have $[0,1]\cap (\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}) = (\cup_0^9A_i) \cup B$. Since $m[[0,1]\cap (\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})] = 1$, we have $1 = 10 m[A_2] + m[B]$. From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76342/measure-of-reals-in-0-1-which-dont-have-4-in-decimal-expansion/76351), $m[B] = 0$, and thus we have $m[A_2] = 1/10$.